# Unable to set write permission on file

Tags: vb.net, acl, file-security

I want to create a file and give a user write permission.

```
IO.File.Create(Path & "\test.json")
Dim fs As Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity = IO.File.GetAccessControl(Path & "\test.json")
Dim far As Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule = New Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\USER", Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteData, Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow)
fs.AddAccessRule(far)
```

When I check the Security tab for this file, I see no changes. VS2015 output window does not show any exceptions. VS2015 is running as Administrator.

I used this for reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49cww7f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

All you have changed in your code is the in-memory file security. In order to apply these changes to the file, you must call [SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
File.SetAccessControl(Path & "\test.json", fs)
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was only in memory. Wow I completely missed the last step.